# Is there a tool to directly run programs with arguments?

Tags: command-line, arguments, executable

I´m searching for a tool with which I can directly start a program providing command line arguments under windows. In Visual Studio I have the option to set start arguments, but it´s not that comfortable for debugging. Also I use Other IDEs too which don´t have this built-in option. Does anyone know such a tool?

Comment: Can you not do that with `cmd` ?

Comment: That would be as inefficient as the Visual Studio built-in option... I need something easy and fast. And open the cmd, navigate to my path, run my program with arguments takes way too long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool named **Args[]** which is context menu based. When you rightclick an exe-file you can choose "Start with arguments". You may download the latest version of the tool as Installer [here](http://uploaded.net/file/cjjsqi78).

Comment: this tool is perfect, thanks